# SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 7 Starter?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried installing SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine running Windows 7 starter but got an error:

> An error occurred during the
>   installation of assembly
>   'Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,version="8.0.50727.1833",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'.
>   Please refer to Help and Support for
>   more information. HRESULT: 0x800736B3.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is SQL Server 2008 not compatible with my OS??

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of the officially supported Windows versions for SQL Server 2008 R2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx.

As it could be expected, Windows 7 Starter is not a supported O.S. for any SQL Server 2008 R2 edition; I personally don't think this means that it would *technically* not be able to run there... but it's definitely not supported.

Comment: Note: all other Win7 editions are supported for SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

[Known bug, KB 961894?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961894)